# On :focus issues with RokNav Fusion menu in Gantry (for joomla)

Tags: menu, accessibility

I am having issues with my websites menu: I am trying to make it more accessible, so using the :focus so the website can be navigated with Tab and Shift+Tab - but the submenu (the dropdown) is not receiving any focus but the 5 main tabs receive focus - how can I fix this issue? Ive looked for solutions to my problems but cannot find any relevent information to the specific menu system I am using (Fusion menu by RokNav), any help would be greatly appreciated... http://www.encoretelesolutions.com for example

Dave

Comment: Dave- The problem is actually larger than getting `:focus` to work. One of the things that isn't in my dev toolbox isn't the ability to say how to fix the menu. Can you use say a jQuery or a YUI menu instead?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Ill look into a few new menu options!

Comment: Welcome, I wish i could just say do _x_, but in cases like this that usually isn't an option